# Declaring div variables inside or outside of a loop with appendChild

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some JavaScript practice after a few years without working with it, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I started with a simple loop to output "Hello, world!" a few times:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Hello, world!";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

That gave me five lines of "Hello, world!". I wanted to see if the code would run faster if I moved the variable declaration out of the loop:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Hello, world!";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

I expected to get five lines of "Hello, world!" but I only got one. Can someone explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: It's because in the second example, you're not *creating* any more div's, you're appending the same div to the body and since it's already there, nothing additional happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are creating a new element on each iteration and appending it.

In the second snippet, you are creating a *single* element, and then essentially moving it five times.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> The [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) **moves it from its current position to the new position**. This means that a node can't be in **two points of the document simultaneously**. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position.

Therefore, you should clone the element before appending it by using the [`.cloneNode()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Hello, world!";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
    document.body.appendChild(div.cloneNode(true));
}
```